# Unix Running Tar Command

Tags: shell, unix, tar

I have created a shell script, which is designed to perform an upgrade of a system.

On the terminal screen, we only want to print a few messages to inform the user of the progress of the update.

Part of the update creates a tar file of a folder for backup purposes - but when the tar command is run, it lists on the screen all the files and folders currently being tar-ed - is it possible to stop this information appearing on the terminal screen?

```
tar -cvf backup.tar.gz /folder_anme/
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Omit `v` option:

```
tar cf backup.tar.gz /folder_anme/
```

---

According to GNU tar(1) manpage:

> **-v, --verbose**
>
> ```
>     verbosely list files processed
> ```